# Chrome extension global error/exception handler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have window.onerror function on the top to catch all error in chrome extension
It works fine for plain code but do not catches error inside the chrome.runtine.sendMessage  and at some other points as well

```
case 'favorite':
           
               //any error here is caught by window.onerror()

               chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'FetchData', tokenData }, function (response) {
                   if (response) {
                       //any error here is **not** caught by window.onerror()
                       }

               });
               //any error here is caught by window.onerror()

           
           break;
```

OnError function

```
window.onerror = function (error, url, line) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't, take a look at this bug first:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357568

But there is this little trick to use a `timeout` to change the execution order of your code. for example:

```js
window.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log('Caught error:', e);
}


chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  type: 'FetchData',
  tokenData
}, function(response) {
  if (response) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      throw 'Your Error';
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

you can also define a global wrapper for this snippet of yours. This way you dont need to  create a timeout every time

```js
window.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log('Caught error:', e);
}


chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  type: 'FetchData',
  tokenData
}, chromeExtensionErrorsWrapper(function(response) {
  if (response) {
    throw 'Your Error';
  }
}));


function chromeExtensionErrorsWrapper(fn) {
  return function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return setTimeout(function() {
      fn.apply(null, args);
    }, 0);
  };
}
```

Comment: Actually after getting response i have to do some scrapping and data filling in forms and html elements, so often HTML elements get change and i have to debug whole thing to find what actually changed. So i was putting these error as log to find the problem directly.
and there are alot of settimeout already in it, and i need the actual JS error which it show on console not the custom.